# Is it possible to set repeating times of vibration pattern of a Notification Chanel for Android SDK 26

Tags: android, vibration, notification-channel

I am trying to use a custom vibration on local notifications. After reading a bit I set the custom vibration pattern in the Notification Channel, like this:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val notificationChannel =
            NotificationChannel(NotificationChannels.CHANNEL_ID, channelName, importance)

        ...

        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)
        notificationChannel.vibrationPattern = vibrationPattern
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
    }
```

But it vibrates only once and executes only the first four indexes.

For example, if my pattern looks like this:

```
val vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(
        0, 200, 500, 50,
        0, 200, 500, 50,
        0, 200, 500, 50,
        0, 200, 500, 50,
        0, 200, 500, 50,
        0, 200, 500, 50)
```

It vibrates only regarding the first row and stops. The vibrations are equivalent to this:

```
val vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0, 200, 500, 50)
```

I had an idea to set the pattern to look like the last one and to set the system to repeat it several times, but I did not find how to do it so far.

I will be glad to get some help here.

Answer (score 7):

use this :

```
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT
```

before putting into `NotificationManager.notify`

Comment: vibration does not stop after cancelling notification. It does not stop even after force stopping the app. The sound stops. Could you please help?